# How to stop sushi nori tasting too strong?

Tags: vegetarian, sushi

Vegetarian here (who doesn't eat fish), I love sushi and I've made it a few times at home and the technique is relatively pain free but the taste is just... off.

From a shop, usually Yo-Sushi or recently Wasabi (which is an amazing oriental place I might add.) - it's delicious. The sea/fishy flavour of the nori is perfectly balanced but when I make it at home all it tastes of is seaweed. It feels like I'm licking an eel it's so damn strong.

How do I make the nori have less flavour? It completely over powers everything and by the time I'm finished I feel sick from the strong taste. It's not so bad the next day after it's been in the fridge but there must be something I'm doing wrong?

The nori I buy is from the supermarket and I believe it's Kikoman branded, I have some more authentic imported stuff sitting in the cupboard which I haven't used yet. Could it simply be that the stuff from the shop isn't fresh? Having said that I've had to wait for my sushi to be made and it was still delicious, so perhaps the nori I bought was just different?

Comment: Are you sure the nori is less flavorful as opposed to your other fillings being too bland, making it stand out too much? Try tearing off a bit of the nori you like and tasting it alone, then comparing with your brand.

Comment: Maybe you could try a different brand?

Comment: Are you toasting your nori? I find that makes it taste more nutty and less fishy (and the nutty flavor kind of gets lost in the rice).

Answer (score 6):

It does sound more like a balance of flavours issue... Are you adding rice vinegar, sugar and salt to your rice once it is cooked? If not your rice will be less flavoured and therefore the nori would taste stronger in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you can toast nori, but I suspect that it would result it more flavor, not less.

You could try making larger rolls, so the proportion of nori to rice and filling is less, or make an ‘inside out’ roll, which was specifically intended to limit the eater’s exposure to nori (for American palettes)

Or you could make other shapes of sushi that don’t require nori— nigiri, [chirashi](https://www.allaboutsushiguide.com/chirashi-sushi.html), [oshi](https://www.allaboutsushiguide.com/oshi-sushi.html), etc.